# Use Skype with Google app engine xmpp api

Tags: google-app-engine, skype

Can we use skype with google app engine xmpp api? As we can send our chat message to any gmail id(JID), can we use skype id as JID in google app engine xmpp api? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there are two third-party gateways that claim to be a xmpp-skype bridge, however, both seem to be non-functional at the moment.  (Or maybe I was just unable to figure out how to install them correctly.)

JabberSkype: http://jameslow.com/work/jabberskype/

Karaka: https://code.google.com/p/karaka/

I know this doesn't really answer the question, since it doesn't provide a working xmpp/skype setup, but it's the best I've been able to find.  Hopefully this answer can be edited in the future if/when either of these projects see some more life.